# Text file whitespace can`t be removed in Python

Tags: python, io, numpy, text-files

I have a text file that is ordered in this fashion:

```
1,1,1,
1,1,1,
1,1,1,
```

My Python script will read each individual line in the text file as a string, delimit based on comma, then convert it to a decimal number for graphing and analysis. I want to create a single array composed of the merged lines such as below:

```
[1,1,1
 1,1,1
 1,1,1]
```

I`ve tried using the vstack method from numpy but it seems that there is a whitespace leftover in the text file that I cannot get rid of.

```
>>> 
[735019.6277, 0.0, 1.0178, 3.0, -2.104]
[735019.6278, 0.0, 15.361, 3.0, -2.078]
[735019.628, 0.0, 29.579, 3.0, -2.0682]
[]
```

Because of this space, I cannot join each line into a single array.

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import *

file = open("results_test.txt", 'r')
line = file.readline()
data = line.split(',')
data[-1] = 0
table = data
x = 0
while (x < len(table)):
    table[x] = float(table[x])
    x = x+1
del(table[-1])
print table

while line:
    line = file.readline()
    data = line.split(',')
    data[-1] = 0
    x = 0
    while (x < len(data)):
        data[x] = float(data[x])
        x = x+1
    del(data[-1])
    print data
    table = vstack((table,data))

file.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\read_txt.py", line 26, in <module>
    table = vstack((table,data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 226, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_2d,tup),0)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0
```

Any thoughts on what this space is and how to get rid of it so that I may use the vstack method?

Comment: maybe you can use `strip()` to get rid of extraneous characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of the error proneness of while loops. Try to avoid them.

First you check if line isn't empty (`while line`) and **then** you read a new line (`line = file.readline()`). This makes the check rather useless.

Instead, use `for line in file`, and delete the `line = file.readline()` line.

Comment: `for line in file` is better than `for line in file.readlines()` since it will read one line at a time and doesn't have to read and store the whole file in memory at once.

Comment: @Matt: True, I'll change that! My main point is though, don't use while loops.

Comment: WOW. Thanks Junux and Matt! That totally did the trick! I was wracking my brain trying to get rid of the mysterious whitespace using strip() and other methods. Now to understand what I just did :p.

Answer (score 1):

For removing extra whitespace in the data you read, simply do this for each line:

```
data = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = []
for line in file:
    data.extend(int(x) for x in line.split(',') if not x.isspace())
```

Comment: Why would you need to do a `strip()` operation on a string that will be converted into an `int()`? `int("1")` yields the same answer as `int("    1     ")`.

Comment: @JoelCornett Thank you, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above, use [strip(](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.rstrip)) to clean your data. Change your

```
data = line.split(',')
```

to

```
data = line.split(',')
data = [i.strip() for i in data] # insert this line
```

You might also want to consider using this construct to open your file, the advantage is that it will take care of closing the file for you when you are done, and also in case an exception occurs.

```
with open("results_test.txt") as file:
    line = file.readline()
      ...
```

Comment: This won't account for possible whitespace in between the numbers.

Comment: @Matt `s = '3.5     5.3   6.0'` yields `['3.5', '5.3', '6.0']` .. or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing that his file is delimited by commas.

Comment: @Matt thanks .. let me address that (either by update or delete of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

parse_numbers = lambda s: map(float, filter(None, map(str.strip, s.split(','))))

with open('input.txt') as f:
    result = list(itertools.chain(*map(parse_numbers, f.readlines())))

print result
```